# Pyfst install error

Tags: python, c++, openfst

I'm having trouble installing [Pyfst](http://pyfst.github.io/), which is a Python wrapper for [OpenFst](http://openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/WebHome). I've tried using

```
pip install pyfst
```

but always end up with an error about some "unordered_map" which can't be found. Here's part of the stack trace:

```
In file included from fst/_fst.cpp:321:

/usr/local/include/fst/symbol-table.h:26:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found

#include <unordered_map>
```

Comment: I have had the same error. There's an open issue here:
https://github.com/vchahun/pyfst/issues/24

Answer (score 4):

Figured out a solution...

Environment: Ubuntu Server 14.04

Build and install OpenFST:

```
mkdir openfst
cd openfst
wget http://www.openfst.org/twiki/pub/FST/FstDownload/openfst-1.5.0.tar.gz
tar zxf openfst-1.5.0.tar.gz
cd openfst-1.5.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The Magic:

```
sudo CFLAGS="-std=c++0x" pip install pyfst
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm running Mac OSX, and I got as far as ./configure before I hit the following error:    

    `checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in '/Downloads/openfst/openfst-1.5.0':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.`

Comment: Edit: fixed the above error by installing the latest Xcode tools and now running `./configure` without any errors so far.

Comment: Last update: I was able to run the `./configure` and `make install` commands as directed. However when I tried running `pip install` as directed I got a similar `unordered map error`:  

`/usr/local/include/fst/symbol-table.h:26:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
    #include <unordered_map>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1`

Answer (score 1):

i also came across the problem，but i solved it easily!

https://github.com/UFAL-DSG/pyfst

You should install OpenFst first,then to install fst!For more details,look at the link above.

Comment: @leaf: Consider describing the answer here, in case that github page goes down.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me and I get a c++ error =>

c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libstdc++'
command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1